# BASE tag with locationProvider AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

My English is not very good, but i try to explain my self clear. I'm trying to optimize Website based on pure Angular to SEO.
Here is the link http://www.sanjosejumpstart.com/tests/project/
When you come first time to the website and start clicking on the links, routing is working fine, but when refreshing the page, i get error with

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /tests/project/automotive was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

i can't understand why this happens.(may be because a hash is disappeared?)

Some body have any idea how i can fix that?

BASE tag on index html looks

```
 <base href="http://www.sanjosejumpstart.com/tests/project/">
```

and route config look likes:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',   '$locationProvider', 
 function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(LockJS.postConvert);
                                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('Interseptor');

 /* activating html5 mode */
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
     url: '/home',
      views: {
       '': { 
         templateUrl: 'templates/main-page-content.html' 
       },
       'article@home': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/main-page/app-main-article.html',
          controller: 'MainArticleCtrl'
        },
        'services@home': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/main-page/app-main-services-list.html',
           controller: 'MainServicesCtrl'
        },
        'services-info@home': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/main-page/app-services-info.html',
            controller: 'MainServicesInfoCtrl'
        },
        'aside@home': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/main-page/app-aside-content.html'
        },
        'middle-slider@home': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/main-page/app-middle-slider.html'
        },
        'map@home': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/main-page/app-map.html'
        }
      }  
    })
    .state('automotive', {
       url: '/automotive',
       views: {
         '': {
           template: '<h1>automotive view</h1>'
         }
       }
    })
  
  }])
```

And then comes more states.
Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your server to return your `index.html` page for all requests that are not:

- an API call (have these all start with `/api` to make this easier)
- a static file request (have these all start with `/pub` or similar)

Then the `index.html` will load, Angular will bootstrap your app, which will involve examining the route and loading the correct page.

#### Why should I use `/api` or `/pub`?

The exact prefix is not super important (though it should make sense). What is helpful is that by using a common prefix for all API endpoints (e.g. routes you call using the `$http` or `$resource` services), you will not overlap with any client-side routes in your app.

For example, if you didn't follow this rule, say you had the following server side route configured:

- `/products` - gets a list of products as JSON

Then you had a client-side route set up as: `/products`, it becomes a bit confusing as to which one you meant when you type in `www.myserver.com/products`.

*Technically, if the server is configured correctly it could tell the difference between an AJAX request to `/products` asking for JSON and a "normal" HTTP GET request to `/products`. But it is still not ideal, because you can't tell from the URL alone which one you meant. You have to look at how it was called as well.*

#### Alternative: Give up on HTML5 mode

If you can't configure the server like I said above, you will need to disable HTML5Mode. That way, all the relative URLs will be after the `#`, so the only file request the web server ever gets is for the default page for `/test/project`.

Comment: set up your server to return your index.html, you meaning with .htaccess? and what you meanin about saying - have these all start with /api to make this easier. thank you for advice

Comment: That might be one way if you are using Apache, yes. It depends completely on what server you are using, that is up to you to figure out. If after you research it and try it yourself, you can ask another question if you get stuck.

Comment: yes i'm using Apache. but i'm not so good in configuring .htaccess files

Comment: I feel your pain, they confuse me too on the few times I have used them. Luckily for you, there is plenty of help out there on how to configure them correctly. That is a separate problem to this question, however.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, you can see all redirects now:

http://www.sanjosejumpstart.com/tests/project/home

here is the solution:

Apache server

1) index must be php, not html - index.php

2) adding BASE tag in head of the file like this = `<base href="/tests/project/">`

3) in app config -  `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

no need to add   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

and finally .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /Locksmith-Project/project/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)       index.php/#/$1 
</IfModule>
```

Hope it is be helpful to someone